# request Header fields too large axios error , error code 431

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, axios

*** when m making request with axios m getting this eror , i dont know how to resolve this ***

*** home page component , where m making request  ***

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router";
import Header from "../../header/Header";
import Posts from "../../posts/Posts";
import Sidebar from "../../sidebar/Sidebar";
import "./homepage.css";
import axios from 'axios'

export default function Homepage() {
  const [posts , setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPost = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("/posts")
      setPosts(res.data)
    } 
    fetchPost()
},[])

  const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location);
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className="home">
        <Posts posts={posts} />
        <Sidebar />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

*** my backend server connection file ***

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
const userRoute = require("./routes/users");
const postRoute = require("./routes/posts");
const categoryRoute = require("./routes/categories");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");

dotenv.config();
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/images")));

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL)
  .then(console.log("Connected to MongoDB"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, req.body.name);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
app.post("/api/upload", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json("File has been uploaded");
});

app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/posts", postRoute);
app.use("/api/categories", categoryRoute);

app.listen("3000", () => {
  console.log("Backend is working at 3000");
});
```

*** error that  m getting ***

code
:
"ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
config
:
{transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}
message
:
"Request failed with status code 431"
name
:
"AxiosError"
request
:
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
response
:
{data: '', status: 431, statusText: 'Request Header Fields Too Large', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
stack
:
"AxiosError: Request failed with status code 431\n    at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:50094:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48834:66)"
[[Prototype]]
:
Error

Answer (score 0):

You can set limit in express.

Example:

```js
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from "body-parser"

const app = express()

app.use(express.json({ limit: "10mb" }))
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "10mb" }))

// Your api routes
```

Comment: didn't worked bro and can u please tell me what can be causing this problem

Comment: https://bityl.co/FOmR  
Have a look at this article